# Can .NET v3.5 assembly reference .NET v4.5 assembly?

Tags: .net, .net-framework-version

I have a .NET assembly built in v3.5, and i want that this assembly may reference a .NET assembly built in v4.5. Is this possible? If not, is there any workaround?

Example: v3.5 => v4.5 (v3.5 references v4.5)

Tks

Comment: That doesn't sound like a good idea, but... honestly, you probably shouldn't be doing new work on *either* of those frameworks (although I'll grudgingly note the 2023 end-of-life for 3.5 SP1, which is mostly a side-effect of being tied to the OS; it doesn't mean it is a good thing)

Comment: @MarcGravell, actually is 3.5 (without SP1), that's what the customer have in prod environment, and because of other applications at this moment it's not possible to upgrade to a newer version. The purpose of this is to call the 4.5 assembly that have calls to services with TLS1.2, as i have read, 3.5 cannot call services with TLS1.2 (3.5.1 can).

Comment: @Pl4tinum: Since 3.5 (without SP1) is completely out of support and does not get security patches, I sincerely hope that (a) your application only runs inside a tightly controlled intranet and (b) those "services" it connects to (which you want to upgrade to TLS 1.2) are completely trustworthy internal services under your control. Otherwise, it sounds like a security incident waiting to happen...

Comment: @Heinzi, most of the services are using TLS1.2 (v4.5). The ones that are in 3.5 (TLS1.0), are going to be migrated (somehow) to TLS 1.2. In this particular case, the are in a 3.5 assembly, and in this case i cannot upgrade to 4.x

Answer (score 2):

> I have a .NET assembly built in v3.5, and i want that this assembly may reference a .NET assembly built in v4.5. Is this possible?

No.

> If not, is there any workaround?

Any of the following might work:

- Get the source code of the library and try to backport it to v3.5.
- Upgrade your .NET assembly to v4.5.
- Create a small v4.5 exe whose only purpose is to host your v4.5 library. Your v3.5 application can remote-control your v4.5 exe via named pipes, WCF or any other inter-process communication protocol supported by both .NET 3.5 and 4.5.

(We actually implemented the latter approach in a .NET 3.5 project that needed to use a hardware device whose .NET "driver library" was only available as .NET 4. Fortunately, a short time later we got clearance to upgrade the whole project to 4.8, use the library directly and throw away this "out-of-process proxy".)

Comment: Yes upgrading to v4.x should be the best approach, but in this case i can't do that, for now. That out-of-proccess proxy, may be one solution, but i am trying to avoid that.

Comment: I have implemented an "out-of-process" solution based on COM, and it works. For complex types returned in COM method, they are serialized.